# Can i use a Polycom CX100 speakerphone as generic speaker?

Tags: windows-7, speakers, polycom

I've rescued an abandoned Polycom CX100 from a dumpster, in hopes of replacing my adapterless desk speakers.

Unfortunately, the drivers that Windows 7 installed only make it play sound from Lync and Volume Control, even after disabling exclusive control of the device. Google was of no help. Has anyone gotten a CX100 to play audio from other, non-phone applications?

Comment: Would anyone care to explain the downvote? Surely this is a computer hardware/software usage problem which i've attempted to solve myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Yes you can!**](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-change-default-playback-recording-audio-device) Simply set it as default playback device:

[image]

I overlooked the "Default Device" option and went to check the Properties of the device instead.